# Incompatible types required boolean found void?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm currently trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game as a personal project during the summer. Not sure why this code isn't working in my button listener class here it is. btn1 is a JButton. and turn is a boolean variable that is initially true;

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(btn1.setEnabled(true)){ //the clause inside the if statement?
            if(turn){
                btn1.setText("X");
                turn = false;
            }
            else{
                btn1.setText("O");
                turn = true;
            }
            btn1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `JButton.setEnabled()` doesn't return a `boolean`. It's `void` return type.

Answer (score 3):

This code return void

```
if(btn1.setEnabled(true)){
```

maybe you mean

```
if(btn1.getEnabled()){
```

Answer (score 1):

[`setEnabled(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setEnabled(boolean)) is a void method, that means it returns nothing, But when checking `if()` you need to pass Boolean inside. So consider changing that to `if(btn1.getEnabled())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If condition in java requires a boolean input, but you are passing the void :

```
if(btn1.setEnabled(true))
```

Hence the error "Incompatible types required boolean found void".